# cancel editing function doesn't work in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm having troubles figuring out why I can't cancel edit of one of my inputs.
Code snippets are below.
Can anyone point to the mistake there, please?

Here is an input:

```
        <div v-if="!showInput" @dblclick="showInputChange" class="name-team">
            {{ team.team_name }}
        </div>
        <div v-if="showInput" class="change-input">
            <input type="text" v-model="changeTeamName" @keyup.esc="cancelEdit" @blur="cancelEdit" 
            @keyup.enter="cancelEdit" placeholder="Введите новое название">
        </div>
```

Data:

```
        data() {
        return {
            showInput: false,
            teamName: '',
            changeTeamName: '',
            beforeEditCache: '',
        }
    },
```

And cancel edit function:

```
            cancelEdit: function() {
            this.changeTeamName = this.beforeEditCache;
            this.showInput = false;
        }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Copying an object to another variable using simple assignation syntax in Vue keeps the two objects linked, so any changes made to one will be made to the other. That's why when you try to cancel edits using the `beforeEditCache`, it doesn't work because the data has been changed in both instances.

To get round this, use the JavaScript [`Object.assign()` method,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or [Lodash's `cloneDeep` function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) for arrays and nested objects.